Stars and bars intuition, what if all the bars are consecutively lined up on one side?
I had a question regarding the stars and bars method. Suppose were to assign 10 items into 3 bins. Standard stars and bars application says we display the problem something like this with 2 partitions:
***|***|****
From there we can do our standard N choose # Of Partitions. I understand this. However, what if all the bars were on side like this:
||********** or like this: **********||
To me this implies that in this instance all the items are sent into bucket 1, and buckets 2 and 3 are left empty?
But doesn't this overcount the number of ways of all the items can be put into bucket 1? Furthermore, where does this take into account that all the items can be put into buckets 2 or buckets 3? It seems to me we're missing those 2?
There's something intuitively I'm not grasping here, I understand you can arbitrarily assign any of the buckets as bucket 1, but I still feel as though we're undercounting since if enumerate all the possibilities there's no way for one of the other buckets to claim all the stars

Put a bar at each end to flesh out your options

@RobinSparrow oh my god. I see
||xx.... all in bin one. |***...| all in bin 2.  ****...|| All in in bin 3? Damn that was obvious, I can't believe I struggled with that for so long.

$||$ means all items are in bucket $3$ and $||$ means all items are in bucket $1$. And $|********|$ mean all the items are in bucket $2$.  And $||****$ would mean $3$ intems are in bucket 1, $7$ are in bucket $3$ and none are in bucket 2.  Why do you think this is overcounting?  If you think about it it is a perfect one-to-one notation for ways to put items in buckets  .

@fleablood you are correct, I was thinking about it incorrectly.

For $k$ divisions you have $k-1$ dividers, so whatever is on the ends on either side is a bin. The 4th bin would be between divider $k_3$ and $k_4$ going left to right, the 5th bin those to the right of $k_4$.

It is exactly like separating M&Ms with toothpicks.

@RobinSparrow I think I figured out why I was struggling with it. I was imagining all the stars laid out, and then I was inserting partitions in between, my way of thinking kept leading me to always having some in the first partition. I thought about it in terms of boxes and then just removed some of the extra partitions and that helped. Combinatorics is just a subject I feel like I'll never understand ha, even on simple problems my intuition just completely betrays me.
